# How to get transparent JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency

When I try to run to get transparent frame it shows exception.

My code is:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this, 0.05f);
    }
```

Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated
at java.awt.Frame.setOpacity(Frame.java:960)
at java.awt.Window$1.setOpacity(Window.java:4032)
at com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(AWTUtilities.java:174)
at test.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:28)
at test.NewJFrame$2.run(NewJFrame.java:115)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `setUndecorated(true)` before you call `setWindowOpacity`.

In Java 7+ this support is provided in the core API (without the need to use a `com.sun.*` library). See [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) for more details. For example, you could use `JFrame#setOpacity` instead...

```
this.setOpacity(0.05f);
```

Oh, and despite what the tutorial might suggest, I believe the only way to make a decorated window transparent is when the window is NOT using the OS provided decorations (and is using the look and feel provided decorations, which not all look and feels support), but I could be wrong

Comment: i m using netbeans 8.1 , and i also try to  setUndecorated(true) but error is same.

Comment: Netbeans as nothing to do with, it has to do with the version of Java you're using.  Is the window visible when you try and un-decorate it or change it's opacity

Comment: jdk-8u5-windows-i586, code is   try {
           
            this.setUndecorated(true);
            this.setOpacity(0.5f);
            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            //System.out.println(e);
        }
   Exception is :java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable.

Comment: You've tried to modify the state after it's all attached to a native peer, either it's visible or you've set it's size in some way...

Comment: java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable.

Comment: Is there any way to do that without losing decoration?

Comment: @Cornelius At the time of writing, none that I was aware of, it was two years ago and I've not tried lately

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for answering anyway. I ended up adding my own icons in upper right corner.

Comment: For future readers of this post, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56961097/6579265) where you can do it while using `System Look & Feel`.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. A be prepared for it to blow up in your face ... just saying ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I did not understand what you mean :(

Comment: @GeorgeZ. Any solution which relies on reflection is a "hack" at best and is prone to either breaking in future releases or breaking on different platforms. I've not tested this on Mac or Linux, both of which are more sensitive about these types of things. Using reflection this way breaking the intended functionality of the object and could cause untold issues - yes I've done it, yes it's blown up in my face, just saying ;)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative; JavaFX supports transparent windows natively (See for example this [tutorial](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/completely_transparent_windows_stage_in)). If you are just starting with Java GUI programming and have no compelling reason for the use of Swing (ie. a legacy app) I recommend switching to JavaFX. Swing is in maintenance mode and all the new stuff is going into JavaFX. I doubt Swing will ever receive a single new feature from Oracle.